# Codemirror 3 multiplexing modes using simpleHint

Tags: codemirror

So I'm trying to make an SCXML editor which is basically XML (state machine) with JavaScript blocks in it.  I'm close, but I'm having trouble adding hints.  It seems to boil down to I don't know the editing mode I'm in when it comes time to hint.  I've looked in the CodeMirror object for clues but I'm not seeing it.  I'm doing the multiplexing like so:

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("scxml", function (config) {
    return CodeMirror.multiplexingMode(
      CodeMirror.getMode(config, "text/xml"),
      {
          open: "<script>", close: "</script>",
          mode: CodeMirror.getMode(config, "text/javascript"),
          delimStyle: "delimit"
      }
    );
});

editorXml = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editXmlFile"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: 'scxml',
    indentUnit: 4,
    autoCloseTags: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    extraKeys: {
        "'>'": function (cm) { cm.closeTag(cm, '>'); },
        "'/'": function (cm) { cm.closeTag(cm, '/'); },
        "' '": function (cm) { CodeMirror.xmlHint(cm, ' '); },
        "'<'": function (cm) { CodeMirror.xmlHint(cm, '<'); },
        "Ctrl-Space": function (cm) { CodeMirror.xmlHint(cm, ''); }
    }
});
```

Note in the `extraKeys` where the XML hinting is working, how do I get the JavaScript hinting in there?  From the JavaScript hinting help, it appears I'd do something along the lines of:

```
  CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
    CodeMirror.simpleHint(cm, CodeMirror.javascriptHint);
  }

  ... extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"} ...
```

But either way, I need to know the mode I'm in (XML or JavaScript) to know to use `simpleHint` versus `xmlHint`.  Anyone know how this might be done?

EDIT: `cm.getMode().name` and `cm.getOption('mode')` just return `scxml` when I'm in either section

Thanks!

Comment: side note edit: the cm.closeTag didn't work as expected with autoCloseTags so i've removed those two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to dispatch on `CodeMirror.innerMode(cm.getMode(), cm.getTokenAt(POS).state).mode.name`, where `POS` is the `{line, ch}` position that you're interested in. It will return a name like `"xml"` or `"javascript"`, describing the inner mode at that position.