# How to enable code hinting using codemirror?

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete, codemirror

I am using codemirror to allow the user to type anycode like css/html/js.

I need to enable if the user type something like in css mode

```
div {
 padding-
}
```

It should hint the user to chose the available options from the list like

```
div {
padding-top
padding-left
padding-right
padding-bottom
}
```

Something like sublime editor using codemirror. Please see the attached image for the demo of sublime auto hinting

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 <script src="codemirror-5.4/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
  <script src="codemirror-5.4/mode/css/css.js"></script>
  <script src="codemirror-5.4/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
  <script src="codemirror-5.4/addon/display/fullscreen.js"></script>
  <script src="codemirror-5.4/keymap/sublime.js"></script>
  <script src="codemirror-5.4/addon/hint/show-hint.js"></script>
  <script src="codemirror-5.4/addon/hint/css-hint.js"></script>
  <script src="codemirror-5.4/addon/hint/javascript.js"></script>

<h3>Editor</h3>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="textarea2">HTML</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea class="code" name="code" id="codert" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Enter code here ..." style="width: 810px; height: 200px">
       </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="textarea3">CSS</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <textarea id="code" class="code" name="codeCSS"  cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Enter code here ..." style="width: 810px; height: 200px">
        </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="textarea3">javascript</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea id="codeJS" class="code" name="codeJS"  cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Enter code here ..." style="width: 0px; height: 0px">
           </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript code for codemirror**

```
<script>

   function loadCSS() {
    var $head = $("#preview").contents().find("head");                
    $head.html("<style>" + editor.getValue() + "</style>");
}; 

function loadJS() {
    var scriptTag = "<script>"+editorJS.getValue()+"<";
    scriptTag +=  "/script>";

    var previewFrame2 = document.getElementById('preview');
    var preview2 =  previewFrame2.contentDocument ||  previewFrame2.contentWindow.document;
    preview2.open();
    preview2.write(editor2.getValue()+scriptTag);
    preview2.close();

    loadCSS();
};

var delay;
// Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.

// css editor
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/x-scss",
    keyMap: "sublime",
    theme: 'monokai',
    autoCloseTags: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"}
});
editor.on("change", function() {
    clearTimeout(delay);

    delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 0);
});

function updatePreview() {
    loadCSS();
}
setTimeout(updatePreview, 0);


var delay2;
// Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.
var editor2 = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codert'), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/html",
    keyMap: "sublime",
    theme: 'monokai',
    autoCloseTags: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"}
});
editor2.on("change", function() {
    clearTimeout(delay2);

    delay2 = setTimeout(updatePreview2, 0);
});

function updatePreview2() {
    var scriptTag = "<script>"+editorJS.getValue()+"<";
    scriptTag +=  "/script>";

    var previewFrame2 = document.getElementById('preview');
    var preview2 =  previewFrame2.contentDocument ||  previewFrame2.contentWindow.document;
    preview2.open();
    preview2.write(editor2.getValue()+scriptTag);
    preview2.close();

    loadCSS();
}
setTimeout(updatePreview2, 0);


var delayJS;
// Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.
var editorJS = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codeJS'), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: 'javascript',
    keyMap: "sublime",
    theme: 'monokai',
    autoCloseTags: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"}
});
editorJS.on("change", function() {
    clearTimeout(delayJS);

    delayJS = setTimeout(updatePreviewJS, 0);
});

function updatePreviewJS() {
    loadJS();
}
setTimeout(updatePreviewJS, 0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't post all the code so I could be wrong, but make sure to add the `show-hint.css` stylesheet to the page header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../addon/hint/show-hint.css">
```

Otherwise, the hints just don't show up and I for one assumed the autocomplete function was not working.

Answer (score 3):

from the [code mirror website](https://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html)

```
function getCompletions(token, context) {
  var found = [], start = token.string;
  function maybeAdd(str) {
    if (str.indexOf(start) == 0) found.push(str);
  }
  function gatherCompletions(obj) {
    if (typeof obj == "string") forEach(stringProps, maybeAdd);
    else if (obj instanceof Array) forEach(arrayProps, maybeAdd);
    else if (obj instanceof Function) forEach(funcProps, maybeAdd);
    for (var name in obj) maybeAdd(name);
  }

  if (context) {
    // If this is a property, see if it belongs to some object we can
    // find in the current environment.
    var obj = context.pop(), base;
    if (obj.className == "js-variable")
      base = window[obj.string];
    else if (obj.className == "js-string")
      base = "";
    else if (obj.className == "js-atom")
      base = 1;
    while (base != null && context.length)
      base = base[context.pop().string];
    if (base != null) gatherCompletions(base);
  }
  else {
    // If not, just look in the window object and any local scope
    // (reading into JS mode internals to get at the local variables)
    for (var v = token.state.localVars; v; v = v.next) maybeAdd(v.name);
    gatherCompletions(window);
    forEach(keywords, maybeAdd);
  }
  return found;
}
```

you press ctrl+ space to enable code hinting.

Comment: that's for javascript. html function can be found here https://codemirror.net/demo/html5complete.html

Comment: The code you wrote is an example code provided by codemirror for demo. But the functionality won't work only just with that code. By the way, how about css auto hinting? Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: @Packer i said in my answer it was from the website. no idea on the css. there's a big discussion on google groups about it!

Comment: i think this might work http://stackoverflow.com/a/19544473/1675954, any chance of an upvote?

Answer (score 3):

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#bc08cb08dee7609bbe7df11e8a55f27a

There are lots of different ways you can implement code hinting/autocomplete.

```
var arrows = [37, 38, 39, 40]

editor.on("keyup", function(cm, e) {
  if (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) < 0) {
    editor.execCommand("autocomplete")
  }
})
```

Of course Codemirror has [official documentation](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_show-hint) for code hints/autocomplete.
[XML completion](https://codemirror.net/demo/xmlcomplete.html)
[HTML completion](https://codemirror.net/demo/html5complete.html)
[JavaScript completion](https://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html)

You can [view the source](http://view-source:https://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html) for the javascript example to learn how to make your own hints too.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I enabled custom code hinting in my application's UI using CodeMirror 5

(it's basically a hodgepodge made out of several solutions I found online and from the source code at https://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html)

First of all I added CodeMirror and the code hint plugin

```
<script src="libs/codemirror-5/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/codemirror-5/plugins/show-hint.js"></script>
```

I overloaded (is that the right term?) the `showHint` command, placed it in a function (note that because CM calls this function, it will inject the instance context as a usable argument).

```
function getSnippets(codemirror) {

    let snippets = [
        {text: 'SELECT', displayName: 'select'},
        {text: 'UPDATE', displayName: 'update'},
        {text: 'CREATE', displayName: 'create'},
        // other snippets for hinting
    ]

    CodeMirror.showHint(codemirror, function () {

        let cursor = codemirror.getCursor();
        let line = codemirror.getLine(cursor.line);
        let start = cursor.ch, end = cursor.ch;
        // corrects ignoring trailing whitespaces removal
        while (start && /\w/.test(line.charAt(start - 1)))
                    --start;
        while (end < line.length && /\w/.test(line.charAt(end)))
                    ++end;
        const token = codemirror.getTokenAt(cursor);
        const currentWord = token.string;

        // reduce hint options if user has already entered something
        const list = snippets.filter(function (item) {
            return item.displayText.indexOf(currentWord) >= 0;
        });

        return {
            list: list.length ? list : snippets,
            from: CodeMirror.Pos(cursor.line, start),
            to: CodeMirror.Pos(cursor.line, end)
        };
    }, {completeSingle: true});
}
```

Then, inside the codemirror instance options I defined hint calling by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>, this will call the `getSnippets` function I defined earlier

```
let codemirrorOptions = {
    mode: 'sql',
    extraKeys: {
        "Ctrl-Space": getSnippets
    },
    lineNumbers: false,
    lineWrapping: true
};
```